# MALLOC_CHECK_ not reporting violations

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

I have enabled `MALLOC_CHECK_` by setting it to 1 (tried with 2 and 3 as well) But I don't see it reporting any issues with the following c++ program:

```
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  std::cout<<"n = "<<n<<std::endl;
  char *buf = new char[n];

  for (int i = 0;i < n*n; i++)
  {
    buf++;
    *buf = 'x';
  }



std::cout<<"done"<<std::endl;
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: `char *buf = (char *)malloc(n);`

Comment: operator new may invoke malloc. And in my environment (libstdc++) it is [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc?revision=193295&view=markup)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling 'delete' in the end. For me gcc started flagging errors only when there was a call to 'free' in the end. Maybe an implementation detail.